# Tableau: Four week moving average, first four weeks

Tags: tableau-api

**Setting**

As I'm sure many of you do in your vizs, I use date parameters for my data. This is great for creating trend analyses and all types of time series representations. Currently I'm using a line graph to show our sales hit rate history.

**Picture**

[image]

**Question**

The problem I'm running into is in creating a four week moving average. As you can see the four week moving average doesn't become just that until four weeks in! This creates quite the problem for me. What methods will enable the average at t=0 to show the average for the preceding four weeks?

**Formula Used**

This is my formula for creating the four week moving average:

```
WINDOW_AVG([Hit Ratio],-27,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your date filter and try:

> IIF(ATTR([DATE_FIELD])<*T=0*,NULL,WINDOW_AVG([Hit Ratio],-27,0))

Comment: removing the date filter means users won't be able to adjust the date range. It'll fix the Moving Average but take away the usability.

Comment: Unfortunately, filters are applied before table calcs perform their operations.